# Adding custom javascript to device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my javascripts folder for my rails application, I've added both a device.js file as well as a device/registrations.js file. I was under the impression that when I'm routed to the registration page, rails would automatically pick up the correct javascript files, but for some reason it's not working.

Is there anything that needs to be added so that it can use custom javascript code?

Answer (score 1):

You can include that in your registration view of devise by doing:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'devise/registrations' %>
```

To generate the views do

```
rails g devise:views
```

**EDIT**

Another way would be in the views/devise folder create a partial _registrations.html.erb
Put your js code in there and then do

```
<%= render 'registrations' %>
```

Comment: just to heads up, but you spelled devise incorrectly. I'm unable to edit it as SO requires more than 6 characters to be edited

Comment: yeah i realized it. Just fixed it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Right now, my js code only works if i put it in the application.js file

Comment: @theStig i added a new method. Can you try that?

Comment: I've tried that, and it doesn't work. I'm checking the logs thats outputted from the server and i'm noticing that the js file is getting loaded (from both methods). And, if i copy the exact js code to the applications.js it'll work. I'm trying to see if I need to add some configuration value to devise to accept the js

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52781/discussion-between-leon-and-thestig)